# Problems using Contiki Cooja motes on motes creation

Tags: ant, ipv6, contiki, iot

I have developed a working Cooja simulatation that uses 1 sky mote (for RPL border router, that did not work with a cooja mote) and 30 Cooja motes.
I run cooja using ant big_mem.
The simulation was working correctly, and then I have saved it.
After quitting cooja I have tried to reuse it, but I always get the following error:

```
se.sics.cooja.GUI$SimulationCreationException: Mote type creation error: Error when creating corecomm instance: Lib4
    at se.sics.cooja.GUI.loadSimulationConfig(GUI.java:3428)
    at se.sics.cooja.GUI.loadSimulationConfig(GUI.java:3340)
    at se.sics.cooja.GUI.doLoadConfig(GUI.java:2397)
    at se.sics.cooja.GUI$4.run(GUI.java:636)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: se.sics.cooja.MoteType$MoteTypeCreationException: Error when creating corecomm instance: Lib4
    at se.sics.cooja.CoreComm.createCoreComm(CoreComm.java:343)
    at se.sics.cooja.contikimote.ContikiMoteType.doInit(ContikiMoteType.java:385)
    at se.sics.cooja.contikimote.ContikiMoteType.configureAndInit(ContikiMoteType.java:348)
    at se.sics.cooja.contikimote.ContikiMoteType.setConfigXML(ContikiMoteType.java:1389)
    at se.sics.cooja.Simulation.setConfigXML(Simulation.java:681)
    at se.sics.cooja.GUI.loadSimulationConfig(GUI.java:3410)
    ... 4 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at se.sics.cooja.CoreComm.createCoreComm(CoreComm.java:334)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: se.sics.cooja.corecomm.Lib4.init()V
    at se.sics.cooja.corecomm.Lib4.init(Native Method)
    at se.sics.cooja.corecomm.Lib4.<init>(Lib4.java:50)
    ... 14 more
```

How can I solve it?
Thank you,
Daniel

Answer (score 2):

I have discovered the problem. It it necessary to delete the obj_cooja folder that the simulation creates to solve the problem